# DateTime Parameters in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have written a stored procedure in SQLServer which accepts 2 parameters, both in dateTime format.  The idea of the stored proc. is for the user to be able to search for specific cases between 2 different dates.  The users are imputing the dates in mm/dd/yyyy format, and this returns data properly.

Now I need to turn this into a Crystal Report.  I set up the report to use the Stored Procedure that I have written.  When Crystal asks for the values of the 2 parameters, it will not accept them as mm/dd/yyyy format.  It is trying to get me to put them in yyyy-mm-dd hr:mn:scds format.

Is there a way I can set up the report to accept the parameters as mm/dd/yyyy format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post what u have tried?

Comment: @hs.chandra, I honestly don't have a whole lot of experience with Crystal Reports.  When setting up the report, all I have really done is set it to used the stored procedure I have written in Sql Server.  It then asks for the parameters when I try to confirm the setup, and it will not accept mm/dd/yyyy format.  I am scared the user will not be able to input mm/dd/yyyy format and get the correct data returned because of this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot control input format for the date parameters

Answer (score 0):

In crystal report, you can right click the date variable and go to format, then choose the way you want the date to appear.

If the date is obtained correctly from the database, you can display it as  you wish by changing the format.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports uses the datatype in the Stored Procedure.  If you have a Date in your SProc Crystal will treat the value as a string and not display the calendar icon in the parameters popup.  Solution is to change the Date to DateTime in your sProc and Crystal will display the calendar icon and format as yyyy-mm-dd automatically if your user clicks on the calendar icon.  I know you probably want a DATE not DATETIME but use DATETIME I don't believe there is any other answer.